# Agrupamento de arrays de forma hierárquica PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura em uma tabela no banco de dados. A minha intenção é que quando eu fizer um `select * from` nela eu eu possa interar sobe os valores de modo que eu tenha um array no estilo hierárquico.
Ou seja, sempre que houver um idFather, esse valor deve ser filho de um id normal que contenha esse valor.

Exemplo:

> ```
> [
>   Id: 01,
>   idFather: null,
>   Name: "Galpão",
>   Sub: [
>      Id: 02,
>      idFather: 01,
>      Name: "Bloco A,
>   ]
> ]
> ```

**ATUALIZADO**

Este é basicamente meu código atual que monta um único objeto sem subcategorias.

O que eu poderia fazer nele para atingir meu objetivo?

```
public function getCategorias(CategoriaCollection $objCategorias){

$data = [];

foreach($objCategorias as $objCategoria){

    $data[] = (object) [
        'id' => $objCategoria->getId(),
        'pai' => $objCategoria->getPai(),
        'nome' => $objCategoria->getNome(),
    ];

}

parent::responderAjax(new AjaxResponse("", $data));
```

}

Alguma sugestão?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: sugestão seria usares uma função recursiva ou seja que chama-se a si mesma, assim poderás montar o pertendido array

Comment: Entendi, mas não estou conseguindo imaginar a lógica para esta função recursa, você poderia dar uma sugestão? Atualizei a pergunta com o meu código atual. @13dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, conforme sugerido neste tópico https://stackoverflow.com/a/8587437/476, segue um exemplo de algoritmo recursivo:

```
function build_tree($nodes, $parent=0)
{
  $branch = [];

  foreach($nodes as $node) {
    if ($node['parent'] == $parent) {
      $childrens = build_tree($nodes, $node['id']);

      if (!empty($childrens)) {
        $node['children'] = $childrens;
      }

      $branch[] = $node;
    }    
  }

  return $branch;

}


$categories = [
    ['id' => 1, 'parent'=> 0, 'name' => 'Galpão'],
    ['id' => 2, 'parent'=> 1, 'name' => 'Bloco A'],
    ['id' => 3, 'parent'=> 1, 'name' => 'Bloca B'],
    ['id' => 5, 'parent'=> 2, 'name' => 'Sala 1'],
    ['id' => 6, 'parent'=> 2, 'name' => 'Sala 2'],
    ['id' => 8, 'parent'=> 3, 'name' => 'Sala 1'],
    ['id' => 9, 'parent'=> 3, 'name' => 'Sala 2'],
];


var_dump(build_tree($categories));
```

Fiz alguns testes e funcionou bem.